Fabric.js : how to generate a PNG with bit depth = 1?
For my project, I use canvas of fabric.js to create an label, that will be print on thermo-thing.
So I need to generate a PNG with bit-depth (color-depth) equals to 1.
I put all my elements with even black or white colors, but canvas.toDataURL( {format: "png"}) create a file with bit-depth equals to 32.
Do anyone knows how I can :

force this bit-depth
or modify generated image depth ?

I saw there is toBlob function, but I don't know if I can do this transformation with it ?
(if some of my english is wrong, sorry, I tried my best)
Thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
